# Initializing a pointer to an array of integers.

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, integer, ansi-c

I have the following problem:
I need to initialize a stuct Number that represents a number, for this it needs to contains its value, amount of divisors and the divisors themself. To store the divisors I need to use a pointer to an array of integers, and this is where the problem starts.

```
 typedef struct {
        int value;
        int divisor_amount;
        int (*divisors)[];
    } Number;
```

Now since I do not know in advance how many divisors my number posseses I cannot give a length to the array.

In the main function I assign each of these fields a value. For the first two variables this is no problem.

```
Number six;
six.value = 6;
six.divisor_amount = 3;
```

Now for the pointer I do not really know how to initialize it. During class it was told to do this as:

```
six.divisors[0] = 1;
six.divisors[1] = 2;
six.divisors[2] = 3;
```

but then I get this erroy from the compiler:

> [Error] invalid use of array with unspecified bounds

So I thought maybe I needed to assign some space and tried:

```
six.divisors = malloc(six.divisor_amount*sizeof(int));
```

But that gives me just another error:

> [Warning] assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by
>   default]

Comment: `int (*divisors)[];` is probably not what you want to have. If you want to have a pointer to an array just write `int *divisors;` and then `malloc` it during initialisation

Comment: I cannot reproduce the warning. As `six.divisors` is a (non-function) pointer type, this should actually work. The error message for the first snippet is the same as `gcc -std=c99` gives, but I don't get the second one. How do you compile?

Comment: I use devcpp with -Wpedantic turned on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int (*divisors)[];
```

is wrong this is a pointer to array of `int`.

use

```
int *divisors;
```

with this your `malloc` allocation should work.